# django gunicorn nginx forward to <domain>/app

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, wsgi

I have searched tutorials and SO all over but unfortunately I still don't understand how to forward requests for my domain to a specific app (not the project).
this is my project structure

```
django_project
||
bjsite
-- settings.py
-- wsgi.py
-- ...
||
bj
-- models.py
-- views.py
-- templates
-- ...
||
manage.py
static
requirements.txt
venv
...
```

in settings.py, this is my
`WSGI_APPLICATION = 'bjsite.wsgi.application'`

gunicorn service

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=bj.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=bj
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/bj/bjsite
ExecStart=/home/bj/bjsite/venv/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile /home/bj/bjsite_deploy/gunicorn_access.log \
          --error-logfile /home/bj/bjsite_deploy/gunicorn_error.log \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/bj.sock \
          bjsite.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and my nginx cong in sites-available

```
server {
listen 80;

server_name domain.de www.domain.de;

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/bj.sock;
    }
   location  /static/ {
        root /home/bj/bjsite_deploy;
    }

    location  /media/ {
        root /home/bj/bjsite_deploy;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.de/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certb>
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.de/privkey.pem; # managed by Cer>
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = www.domain.de) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = domain.de) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


server_name domain.de www.domain.de;
listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Everything works when I add request [www.domain.de/bj](http://www.domain.de/bj) in the browser. But I want to forward [www.domain.de](http://www.domain.de) directly to the app.
After reading die django documentation about the wsgi deployment, I think it might just be the wrong wsgi application callable..?

1. Wrong wsgi application callable?
2. wrong WorkingDirectory in gunicorn.service?
3. wrong proxy_pass in nginx.conf?

What am I missing? Sorry for the millionth question on this matter but other threads had different configurations. I just have Nginx - Gunicorn - Django
many thanks
b

Comment: Update: actually, the solution was even simpler: In project.urls, I just had to specify the route for the page without a slash:   ```urlpatterns = [
    path('', include("bj.urls", namespace='landing')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)```

Answer (score 0):

Update: actually, the solution was even simpler: In project.urls, I just had to specify the route for the page without a slash:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include("bj.urls", namespace='landing')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```